# Como puedo crear una tabla en SQL en base a un Formulario de mas de 40 criterios y necesite hacer consultas para poder sacar unas estadisticas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Soy alguien muy nuevo en el mundo de la programacion y estoy realizando un proyecto en la empresa con Angular y NodeJS para crear un RESTapi y almaceno la informacion en SQL-Server. Soy practicante en esta empresa

El problema radica en que debo hacer un proyecto basado en un formulario que fue creado principalmente en Excel que califica el desempeño mediante mas de 40 items de evaluacion y observar si los cumplio o no, El formulario posee datos como: La fecha, Nombre de la persona que califica el desempeño, el que es evaluado y un id.

Mi cliente pide lo siguiente: Necesita que se haga la comparacion de todos los formularios realizados entre un rango de fechas y entre todos esos formularios poder saber cual es el criterio en el que mas falla la persona que es evaluada
[image: Este son 2 de los 40 items que son necesarios de calificar si se cumplieron o no]

Mi primer intento fue crear la tabla con la informacion y los 40 items que son calificados[image: Intento de tabla]

Pero a la  hora de necesitar hacer la consulta sobre de entre todos los formularios cual es el criterio lo hago de la siguiente manera.
`SELECT * FROM Fmc_Matriz WHERE Respuesta_item1  = 'no cumple' AND Respuesta_item2 = 'no cumple'`.

Y asi hago la comparacion sucesivamente hasta tener los 40 items, Simplemente no da debido a mi inexperiencia y que no poseo la forma de poder crear las tablas de este proyecto para poderlas llenar.

Les agradeceria mucho la ayuda. Feliz dia

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El problema de esta pregunta, radica en que deberiamos enseñarte toda una arquitectura para solucionar esto. Como eres practicante en la empresa, deberian enseñarte ahi, como es que mejor conviene trabajar esto para el cliente. hablas de sql server, pero no se ve como subiste la tabla. Es mas, capaz que deben ser dos tablas.

Comment: Buenas, Alejo, bienvenido al sitio. Aparte de lo que indica @gbianchi, no está muy claro lo que buscas exactamente. ¿No estarás buscando aquel criterio que han fallado más candidatos dado un rango de fechas? ¿donde está ese rango en tu consulta? Si lo que quieres es saber cual es el criterio que más falla una persona, esto supone que dicha persona se presenta a la evaluación varias veces. ¿Esto es así? Si la respuesta a un item es cumple/no cumple, eso está pidiendo un campo booleano en la base de datos, no un String.